How do transformation sequences with different origin points work in SVG?
In order to prepare vector images for use in a production environment or for publication, I have a desire to bring the code of SVG files to a unified form.
Simply put, I have a folder with SVG files, I need to convert the images and compose a single JSON-file (or JS-file) with all the images in a view array, like here
https://github.com/arallsopp/hass-hue-icons/blob/main/dist/hass-hue-icons.js
The images themselves are drawn by different people using different software solutions (inkscape, corel draw, illustrator).
Usually authors of vector images don't care much about such properties as, for example, file size. But I would like to get rid of redundant code in SVG files, giving the code an academically fundamental form, where each lemma has a specific function.
For reconstructing mono-color glyphs, it is important to store only the value of the d attribute of a single <path/> element.
Everything else in the SVG glyph file is common to all images.
Such parameters as fill color or stroke thickness can be set for all images in a single file. for all images in a single place from the outside.
Of course, to get the image code to this form, you have to manually edit each image.
For simple images, this becomes a monotonous chore, which is nice to do because of the visibility of the accumulated results.
But sometimes vector image editors produce code structures that are very difficult code structures to interpret manually.
Sometimes these programs save such code into an SVG file, that is almost impossible to change manually.
In particular, multilayer matrix() transformations requiring calculation of coordinates of each path point are very easy to calculate by computer during rendering, but become a headache for manual editing.
For such cases I decided to write a script that helps to convert SVG file into a form with pre-calculated transformations for all points of <path/>.
It took very little time to write such a script.
It took much more time to study all versions of both SVG and CSS specifications. - Different versions of the same specifications dealt with different issues, and in many places they refer to each other.
In the documents the principles of both 2D and 3D transformations are well described.
But one point seemed to me not fully disclosed.
By multiplying the transformation matrices, one can easily calculate the CTM matrix for a successive series of transformations.
But how CTM matrices are calculated if each transformation has its own different origin points?
Having a little experience with the Canvas API, it is not difficult to guess simply subtract the coordinates of the origin before the transformation and  add the coordinates of the origin after the transformation, like
translate(-originX, -originY) and translate(originX, originY).
But what about if a number of transforms are listed in a single element?
For example,transform=“skewX(45) translate(-100, 0) skewY(-45) skewX(25)” transform-origin=“500 350”.
Here, should the origin be considered before skewX(45) and after skewX(25) or should the origin be considered for each transformation separately? Does the point change along with the space distortion?
To test the algorithm, I made a small SVG file that contains the elements to be converted.
A second after the page loads, the conversion script runs and breaks the original image.
I need to change the code to get the original image.
UPD Added comments to the code.


// regular expression to parse numbers
const rxNumberStr = '[+-]?(?:(?:[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)|(?:\\.[0-9]+)|(?:[0-9]+))(?:[eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?';
// regular expression to  parse next lemma from d attribute of <path> 
const rxDLemmaStr = `[MmLlHhVvCcSsQqTtAaZz]|${rxNumberStr}`;

// D-attribute string parser
// https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData
// https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataBNF
class D {
  // Result of parsing a D-attribute string
  // path: [[cmd, new D.P({x,y}), ...], ...]
  path = [];
  constructor(d) {
    let rx = new RegExp(rxDLemmaStr, 'g');
    let ps = d.match(rx).map(v => ('MmLlHhVvCcSsQqTtAaZz'.indexOf(v) > -1 ? v : parseFloat(v)));
    let cmd, move, ref = D.P.abs(0, 0);
    for (let i = 0, len = ps.length; i < len; ) {
      if (isNaN(ps[i])) cmd = ps[i++];
      this.path.push(({
        m: () => (ref = D.P.rel(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref), ps[i - 3] == cmd ? ['M', move = ref] : ['L', ref]),
        M: () => (ref = D.P.rel(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref), ps[i - 3] == cmd ? ['M', move = ref] : ['L', ref]),
        l: () => ['L', (ref = D.P.rel(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref))],
        L: () => ['L', (ref = D.P.abs(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref))],
        h: () => ['H', (ref = D.P.rel(ps[i++], 0, ref))],
        H: () => ['H', (ref = D.P.abs(ps[i++], ref.y, ref))],
        v: () => ['V', (ref = D.P.rel(0, ps[i++], ref))],
        V: () => ['V', (ref = D.P.abs(ref.x, ps[i++], ref))],
        c: () => ['C', D.P.rel(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref), D.P.rel(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref), (ref = D.P.rel(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref))],
        C: () => ['C', D.P.abs(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref), D.P.abs(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref), (ref = D.P.abs(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref))],
        s: () => ['S', D.P.rel(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref), (ref = D.P.rel(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref))],
        S: () => ['S', D.P.abs(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref), (ref = D.P.abs(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref))],
        q: () => ['Q', D.P.rel(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref), (ref = D.P.rel(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref))],
        Q: () => ['Q', D.P.abs(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref), (ref = D.P.abs(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref))],
        t: () => ['T', (ref = D.P.rel(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref))],
        T: () => ['T', (ref = D.P.abs(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref))],
        a: () => ['A', ps[i++], ps[i++], ps[i++], ps[i++], ps[i++], (ref = D.P.rel(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref))],
        A: () => ['A', ps[i++], ps[i++], ps[i++], ps[i++], ps[i++], (ref = D.P.abs(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref))],
        z: () => (ref = move, ['Z']),
        Z: () => (ref = move, ['Z']),
      })[cmd]());
    }
  }
  // Compile array with absolute coordinates for new <path d="..." />
  get abs() {
    return this.path.map(s => s.map((v, i) => (!i ? v : { H: v.x, V: v.y }[s[0]] || v.abs))).flat(3);
  }
  // Compile array with relative coordinates for new <path d="..." />
  get rel() {
    return this.path.map(s => s.map((v, i) => !i ? v.toLowerCase() : { H: v.x - v.ref.x, V: v.y - v.ref.y }[s[0]] || v.rel)).flat(3);
  }
  // Compile array with transformed absolute coordinates for new <path d="..." />
  transform(matrix) {
    return this.path.map(s => s.map((v, i) => (!i ? v.replace(/[HV]/i,'L') : v.transform(matrix)))).flat(3);
  }
  // Path Point class 
  static get P() {
    return class P {
      x;
      y;
      // Reference point for relative coordinates
      ref;
      constructor(props) {
        Object.assign(this, props);
      }
      // Absolute coordinates
      get abs() {
        return [this.x, this.y];
      }
      // Relative coordinates
      get rel() {
        return [this.x - this.ref.x, this.y - this.ref.y];
      }
      // Transform point with matrix
      transform([a, b, c, d, e, f]) {
        return [this.x * a + this.y * c + e, this.x * b + this.y * d + f];
      }
      // Create point from absolute coordinates
      static abs = (x, y, ref) => new D.P({ x, y, ref });
      // Create point from relative coordinates
      static rel = (x, y, ref) => new D.P({ x: ref.x + x, y: ref.y + y, ref });
    };
  }
}

// Matrix multiplication
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication
const multiply = ([a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1], [a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2]) => [
    a1 * a2 + c1 * b2,
    b1 * a2 + d1 * b2,
    a1 * c2 + c1 * d2,
    b1 * c2 + d1 * d2,
    a1 * e2 + c1 * f2 + e1,
    b1 * e2 + d1 * f2 + f1,
  ];

// Consolidate matrix chain
const consolidate = matrices => matrices.reduceRight((acc, m) => multiply(m, acc), [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]);

// Read SVG element attributes
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGElement/attributes
// returns object with attributes
const readAttrs = (element) => [...element.attributes].reduce((acc, { name, value }) => ((acc[name] = value), acc), {});
// Write SVG element attributes
const writeAttrs = (element, attrs) => Object.entries(attrs).forEach(([attr, value]) => element.setAttribute(attr, value));

// Process SVG shape element
// Shape elements are replaced with new <path d="..." /> element
// Shape element attributes are copied to new <path d="..." /> element
// Shape element must not have child elements
// List of shape elements <circle>, <ellipse>, <line>, <path>, <polygon>, <polyline>, <rect>
function processShape(shape) {
  const shape2path = {
    circle: ({ cx, cy, r, ...attrs }) => [
      `M ${[cx - r, cy]} A ${r} ${r} 0 1 1 ${[cx + r, cy]} A ${r} ${r} 0 1 1 ${[cx - r, cy]} Z`,
      attrs,
    ],
    line: ({ x1, y1, x2, y2, ...attrs }) => [`M ${[x1, y1]} L ${[x2, y2]}`, attrs],
    rect: ({ x, y, width, height, rx = 0, ry = 0, ...attrs }) =>
      rx == 0 && ry == 0
        ? [`M ${[x, y]} h ${width} v ${height} h -${width} Z`, attrs]
        : [
            `M ${[x + rx, y]} h  ${width - 2 * rx}  a ${rx} ${ry} 0 0 1  ${rx}  ${ry}
                              v  ${height - 2 * ry} a ${rx} ${ry} 0 0 1 -${rx}  ${ry}
                              h -${width - 2 * rx}  a ${rx} ${ry} 0 0 1 -${rx} -${ry}
                              v -${height - 2 * ry} a ${rx} ${ry} 0 0 1  ${rx} -${ry} Z`,
            attrs,
          ],
    ellipse: ({ cx, cy, rx, ry, ...attrs }) => [
      `M ${[cx - rx, cy]} A ${rx} ${ry} 0 1 1 ${[cx + 2 * rx, cy]}
                          A ${rx} ${ry} 0 1 1 ${[cx + rx, cy - ry]}
                          A ${rx} ${ry} 0 1 1 ${[cx + rx, cy + ry]}
                          A ${rx} ${ry} 0 1 1 ${[cx - rx, cy]} Z`,
      attrs,
    ],
    polygon: ({ points, ...attrs }) => [`M ${points} Z`, attrs],
    polyline: ({ points, ...attrs }) => [`M ${points}`, attrs],
  };

  // return if shape inside <pattern>, <mask> or <clipPath>
  if (shape.closest('pattern') || shape.closest('mask') || shape.closest('clipPath')) {
    return;
  }

  // create d value for new <path>
  let [d, attrs] = shape2path[shape.tagName](readAttrs(shape));
  // create new <path>
  let path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
  // write attributes from object to <path>
  writeAttrs(path, attrs);
  // set attribute "d"
  path.setAttribute('d', d);
  // replace shape with <path>
  shape.replaceWith(path);
  return path;
}

// process <path /> element
function processPath(path){
  // returns all parent Elements
  const getParents = (element)=>{
    let parents = [];
    while(element !== document.documentElement){
      parents.push(element = element.parentNode);
    }
    return parents;
  }
  // parse transform matrix
  const getMatrix = (transform) => {
    let [a, b, c, d, e, f] = transform.match(/^matrix\(([^)]+)\)$/)[1].split(',').map(Number);
    return [a, b, c, d, e, f];
  }
  // parse transform origin
  const getOrigin = (transformOrigin) => {
    let [x, y] = transformOrigin.split(' ').map(value=>value.trim().replace(/[a-z]+$/i,'')).map(Number);
    return [x, y];
  }
  // calc CTM matrix from transform and origin
  const getCTM = (element) => {
    // very useful function for read computed style
    let style = getComputedStyle(element);
    // no matter how exactly the transform is specified
    // (in attributes or in styles or in individual classes),
    // the function returns transform always in a matrix form
    let transform = style.getPropertyValue('transform');
    let transformOrigin = style.getPropertyValue('transform-origin');
    console.log(transform);
    // if no transform is acquired
    if(!transform || transform == 'none') return [1,0,0,1,0,0];
    // parse transform matrix
    let matrix = getMatrix(transform);
    // parse origin
    let origin = getOrigin(transformOrigin);
    // return consolidate matrix
    return consolidate([[1,0,0,1,...origin], matrix,[1,0,0,1,...origin.map(v=>-v)]]);
    // this variant returns original matrix;
    // return matrix;
  }
  
  // return if <path> inside <pattern>, <mask> or <clipPath>
  if (path.closest('pattern') || path.closest('mask') || path.closest('clipPath')) {
    return;
  }

  // read element transform matrix
  const elementCTM = getCTM(path);
  // get all parent elements
  const parents = getParents(path);
  // clone element transform matrix array
  let resultCTM = [...elementCTM];
  // for each parent
  parents.forEach((parent) => {
    // read parent transform matrix
    let parentCTM = getCTM(parent);
    // calc CTM
    resultCTM = consolidate([resultCTM, parentCTM]);
  });
  
  console.log('resultCTM',resultCTM);

  // read d attribute, parse it, transform each point and join to single string
  let d = new D(path.getAttribute('d')).transform(resultCTM).join(' ');
  // this variant returns absolute coordinates without transform
  //let d = new D(path.getAttribute('d')).abs.join(' ');
  // remove transform attributes
  path.removeAttribute('transform');
  path.removeAttribute('transform-origin');
  // force init transform matrix
  path.style.setProperty('transform','matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)');
  path.style.setProperty('transform-origin', '0 0');
  // set d attribute
  path.setAttribute('d', d);
  // find root element
  let svg = path.closest('svg');
  if(svg){
    // remove element from parent
    path.parentNode.removeChild(path);
    // add element to root
    svg.appendChild(path);
  }
}

// Process <use /> element
function  processUse(element) {
  // read attributes to object
  let attrs = readAttrs(element);
  // get href attribute value
  let sel = attrs.href;
  // find referenced element by href="#id"
  let ref = document.querySelector(sel);
  // clone referenced element
  let clone = ref.cloneNode(true);
  // remove id attribute from clone
  clone.removeAttribute('id');
  // remove href from attribute object
  delete attrs.href;
  // write attributes from object
  writeAttrs(clone, attrs);
  // replace <use> element to clone
  element.replaceWith(clone);
  return clone;
}


// Create matrix from transform attribute
// This fuction does not used.
// Use of getComputedStyle() completely replaces this implementation
function parseTransform (transform) {
  const rxTransformNameStr = '(?:(?:translate|scale|skew)[XY]?)|matrix|rotate';

  const rad = a => a / 57.29577951308232;

  const { sin, cos, tan } = Math;

  const matricies = {
    identity: () => [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    translate: (tx, ty) => [1, 0, 0, 1, tx, ty],
    translateX: tx => [1, 0, 0, 1, tx, 0],
    translateY: ty => [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, ty],
    scale: (sx, sy = sx, cx = 0, cy = 0) => [sx, 0, 0, sy, cx * (1 - sx), cy * (1 - sy)],
    scaleX: (sx, cx = 0) => [sx, 0, 0, 1, cx * (1 - sx), 0],
    scaleY: (sy, cy = 0) => [1, 0, 0, sy, 0, cy * (1 - sy)],
    rotate: (a, cx = 0, cy = 0) => {
      let [s, c] = [sin(rad(a)), cos(rad(a))];
      return [c, s, -s, c, cx * (1 - c) + cy * s, cy * (1 - c) - cx * s];
    },
    skew: (ax, ay = ax) => [1, tan(rad(ay)), tan(rad(ax)), 1, 0, 0],
    skewX: a => [1, 0, tan(rad(a)), 1, 0, 0],
    skewY: a => [1, tan(rad(a)), 0, 1, 0, 0],
    matrix: (a, b, c, d, e, f) => [a, b, c, d, e, f],
  };

  let chain = [...transform.matchAll(new RegExp(`(${rxTransformNameStr})\\(([0-9eE,\\.\\s+-]+)\\)`, 'g'))].map(
    ([, fn, args]) => [fn, [...args.matchAll(new RegExp(rxNumberStr, 'g'))].map(([num]) => parseFloat(num))]
  );

  // For example,
  //    chain = [
  //      [ 'matrix', [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ] ],
  //      [ 'translate', [ 100, 100 ] ],
  //      [ 'rotate', [ 45 ] ],
  //      [ 'scale', [ 2, 2 ] ],
  //    ]

  chain = chain.map(([fn, args]) => matrices[fn](...args));

  // chain = [
  //   [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
  //   [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 100, 100 ],
  //   [ 0.7071067811865476, 0.7071067811865475, -0.7071067811865475, 0.7071067811865476, 0, 0 ],
  //   [ 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0 ]
  // ]

  // returns single matrix
  return consolidate(chain);
}

setTimeout(()=>{

// Replace all <use /> elements to clone elements referenced by the <use>
document.querySelectorAll('use').forEach(processUse);

// Replace all shape elements to <path />
document.querySelectorAll('line, rect, circle, ellipse, polygon, polyline').forEach(processShape);

// Process all <path /> elements
document.querySelectorAll('path').forEach(processPath);   // <--- PROBLEM HERE

}, 2000);
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">

  <g transform="translate(-100,-100)">

    <g id="hexagon" transform="translate(250,220) scale(1,.5)">
      <line id="line" x1="200" x2="500" y1="100" y2="100" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" />
      <g transform="rotate(-120)" transform-origin="500 100">
        <use href="#line" />
        <g transform="rotate(-120)" transform-origin="200 100">
          <use href="#line" />
          <g transform="rotate(-120)" transform-origin="500 100">
            <use href="#line" />
            <g transform="rotate(-120)" transform-origin="200 100">
              <use href="#line" />
              <g transform="rotate(-120)" transform-origin="500 100">
                <use href="#line" />
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>


    <g id="hexagon2" transform="translate(250,720) scale(1,.5)">
      <line id="line2" x1="200" x2="500" y1="100" y2="100" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" />
      <g transform="rotate(60) translate(-300,0)" transform-origin="200 100">
        <use href="#line2" />
        <g transform="rotate(60) translate(-300,0)" transform-origin="200 100">
          <use href="#line2" />
          <g transform="rotate(60) translate(-300,0)" transform-origin="200 100">
            <use href="#line2" />
            <g transform="rotate(60) translate(-300,0)" transform-origin="200 100">
              <use href="#line2" />
              <g transform="rotate(60) translate(-300,0)" transform-origin="200 100">
                <use href="#line2" />
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>

    <use href="#hexagon" transform="scale(1,-1) translate(0,-1200)" />

    <rect x="500" y="500" width="200" height="400" fill="#0008" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" />
    <g transform="translate(-100,-100) skewY(-45)" transform-origin="500 500">
      <rect x="500" y="500" width="100" height="400" fill="#0004" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" />
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(-100,-100) skewY(45)" transform-origin="500 500">
      <rect x="500" y="500" width="100" height="400" fill="#0008" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" />
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(200,-200) skewY(45)" transform-origin="500 500">
      <rect x="500" y="500" width="100" height="400" fill="#0004" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" />
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(200,0) skewY(-45)" transform-origin="500 500">
      <rect x="500" y="500" width="100" height="400" fill="#0008" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" />
    </g>
    <rect x="500" y="300" width="200" height="400" fill="#0004" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" />
  </g>

</svg>




See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

@RobertLongson I read this article quite carefully. The specifications  1 and
2 provide more detailed information.

@RobertLongson It will also be helpful to read this and this

transform-origins are not your problem:  Your post description is excellent, however you should split your post into separate questions as you're facing at least 2 quite complex challenges: 1. decomposing nested <use> references to selfcontained elements 2. "flatten" these elements to more compact <path> elements with implicit coordinates not relying on a mess of parent group transforms. See also "Baking transforms into SVG Path Element commands"

See also this codepen example "fixing" the current use-decomposing. You definitely need to copy the use elements transform to the decoupled/stand-alone clone (e.g by adding a wrapping g group). However, this only solves a part of the problem and won't work for any possible SVG. If your example was actually generated by an existing application/data visualization library – you should definitely ditch it (or warn your contributors): drawing simple polygons with transformed references of a <line> is clunky if not "sadistic". You should file this as a bug!

@herrstrietzel  the link to codepen was copied incorrectly

@herrstrietzel The svg-picture code was written in a synthetic way. All images are taken from public repositories. My intentions are to write a universal script that loaded images from a source, converted it and then anyone interested in the sources of the images would see direct links to the image sources before the conversions. But authors are different, with different style. Look for example openclipart.org or svgrepo. Nowadays it has to process almost every image manually.

@herrstrietzel  At the moment I'm in the process of decorating my Home Assitant server. The script could be something more versatile than the current project. At first I wanted to write a script in nodejs. But later I understood that it would be impossible to do without selenium.

Sorry here is the codepen link

@herrstrietzel SVGO does a completely different job - it compresses SVG files by various methods like merging common colors into separate CSS-classes. All SVGO's work with <path> is rounding long numbers in coordinates, plus removing some characters like optional spaces before negative values or optional 0 before point in values from 0 to 1 (e.g. .45).  I don't have the task of compressing the SVG file. On the contrary, I would keep the spaces for better readability. I would just like to multiply the coordinates of all points of <path> according to the transform matrices.

@herrstrietzel Even if I can't make a universal script to get the finished glyphs, it will help me with manual processing anyway. I can't calculate every coordinate in my mind. I'm not good at multiplying real numbers with 8 digits after the separator. In the worst case scenario, I will make a plugin for VSCode that will display a segment and a specific point on the image where the cursor is in svg-file code. But to display that point, it is necessary to calculate the coordinates correctly.

@herrstrietzel For glyphs from guides 1-3 colors, the image of the picture is not crucial. Only the coordinates of each point are important. Compare the code of typical SVG images and the code of regular OTF fonts. If in the first case you want to get an image, then in the second case you need exact coordinates for each point of each character.

@herrstrietzel Have you really never seen colored OTF fonts?
For example,
google fonts and
fontspace.
They've been around since emoji went from black and white to color.

@herrstrietzel I mean, for glyphs, how they render is less important than how precise their coordinates are.
Glyphs can look terrible at 16x16. But if you stretch the image to 512x512, the lines must be straight and precise. All the irregularities become visible.
So I have to adjust the coordinates manually. Transforms get in the way of this, they become a headache when preparing the image to become a glyph.

@herrstrietzel At the very beginning of the question, I gave an exact example of what I want to extract from SVG images. Decomposition of use already works, shapes converts to path without problems. Only the calculation of the coordinates of points in elements with transformations works with the error. I wanted to ask how transformations with different reference points are calculated, since this is very vague in the specifications.

@herrstrietzel Yes, the question is difficult. I agree that few people could answer it. I don't know how to ask questions on SO correctly.
If I asked a question about transformations without disclosing the context, most likely I would not be understood at all.

I DID IT!
So, the working code is below. This answer was made possible by the source code of the NetSurf Browser SVG renderer.
Also, herrstrietzel helped me a lot. The tip to wrap <use> inside <g> was just right.
In my case, text rendering is not needed. But if someone needs to render text in <path>, then this issue is solved with the help of the opentype library. The library is not very well known, but it works magic. In order to apply text transformations, all texts must be rendered into <path> before all <path> are processed.
What's next? Either the task needs to be more complicated, or I don't even know. If anyone has a more elegant solution or finds a bug in my code, let me know. You'll probably get a bounty.


// regular expression to parse numbers
const rxNumberStr = '[+-]?(?:(?:[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+)|(?:\\.[0-9]+)|(?:[0-9]+))(?:[eE][+-]?[0-9]+)?';
// regular expression to  parse next lemma from d attribute of <path> 
const rxDLemmaStr = `[MmLlHhVvCcSsQqTtAaZz]|${rxNumberStr}`;

// D-attribute string parser
// https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData
// https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataBNF
class D {
  // Result of parsing a D-attribute string
  // path: [[cmd, new D.P({x,y}), ...], ...]
  path = [];
  constructor(d) {
    let rx = new RegExp(rxDLemmaStr, 'g');
    let ps = d.match(rx).map(v => ('MmLlHhVvCcSsQqTtAaZz'.indexOf(v) > -1 ? v : parseFloat(v)));
    let cmd, move, ref = D.P.abs(0, 0);
    for (let i = 0, len = ps.length; i < len; ) {
      if (isNaN(ps[i])) cmd = ps[i++];
      this.path.push(({
        m: () => (ref = D.P.rel(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref), ps[i - 3] == cmd ? ['M', move = ref] : ['L', ref]),
        M: () => (ref = D.P.abs(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref), ps[i - 3] == cmd ? ['M', move = ref] : ['L', ref]),
        l: () => ['L', (ref = D.P.rel(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref))],
        L: () => ['L', (ref = D.P.abs(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref))],
        h: () => ['H', (ref = D.P.rel(ps[i++], 0, ref))],
        H: () => ['H', (ref = D.P.abs(ps[i++], ref.y, ref))],
        v: () => ['V', (ref = D.P.rel(0, ps[i++], ref))],
        V: () => ['V', (ref = D.P.abs(ref.x, ps[i++], ref))],
        c: () => ['C', D.P.rel(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref), D.P.rel(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref), (ref = D.P.rel(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref))],
        C: () => ['C', D.P.abs(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref), D.P.abs(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref), (ref = D.P.abs(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref))],
        s: () => ['S', D.P.rel(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref), (ref = D.P.rel(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref))],
        S: () => ['S', D.P.abs(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref), (ref = D.P.abs(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref))],
        q: () => ['Q', D.P.rel(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref), (ref = D.P.rel(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref))],
        Q: () => ['Q', D.P.abs(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref), (ref = D.P.abs(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref))],
        t: () => ['T', (ref = D.P.rel(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref))],
        T: () => ['T', (ref = D.P.abs(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref))],
        a: () => ['A', ps[i++], ps[i++], ps[i++], ps[i++], ps[i++], (ref = D.P.rel(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref))],
        A: () => ['A', ps[i++], ps[i++], ps[i++], ps[i++], ps[i++], (ref = D.P.abs(ps[i++], ps[i++], ref))],
        z: () => (ref = move, ['Z']),
        Z: () => (ref = move, ['Z']),
      })[cmd]());
    }
  }
  // Compile array with absolute coordinates for new <path d="..." />
  get abs() {
    return this.path.map(s => s.map((v, i) => (!i ? v : { H: v.x, V: v.y }[s[0]] || v.abs))).flat(3);
  }
  // Compile array with relative coordinates for new <path d="..." />
  get rel() {
    return this.path.map(s => s.map((v, i) => !i ? v.toLowerCase() : { H: v.x - v.ref.x, V: v.y - v.ref.y }[s[0]] || v.rel)).flat(3);
  }
  // Compile array with transformed absolute coordinates for new <path d="..." />
  transform(matrix) {
    return this.path.map(s => s.map((v, i) => (!i ? v.replace(/[HV]/i,'L') : v.transform(matrix)))).flat(3);
  }
  // Path Point class 
  static get P() {
    return class P {
      x;
      y;
      // Reference point for relative coordinates
      ref;
      constructor(props) {
        Object.assign(this, props);
      }
      // Absolute coordinates
      get abs() {
        return [this.x, this.y];
      }
      // Relative coordinates
      get rel() {
        return [this.x - this.ref.x, this.y - this.ref.y];
      }
      // Transform point with matrix
      transform([a, b, c, d, e, f]) {
        return [this.x * a + this.y * c + e, this.x * b + this.y * d + f];
      }
      // Create point from absolute coordinates
      static abs = (x, y, ref) => new D.P({ x, y, ref });
      // Create point from relative coordinates
      static rel = (x, y, ref) => new D.P({ x: ref.x + x, y: ref.y + y, ref });
    };
  }
}

// Matrix multiplication
// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication
const multiply = ([a1, b1, c1, d1, e1, f1], [a2, b2, c2, d2, e2, f2]) => [
    a1 * a2 + c1 * b2,
    b1 * a2 + d1 * b2,
    a1 * c2 + c1 * d2,
    b1 * c2 + d1 * d2,
    a1 * e2 + c1 * f2 + e1,
    b1 * e2 + d1 * f2 + f1,
  ];

// Consolidate matrix chain
const consolidate = matrices => matrices.reduce((acc, m) => multiply(acc,m), [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]);

// Read SVG element attributes
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGElement/attributes
// returns object with attributes
const readAttrs = (element) => [...element.attributes].reduce((acc, { name, value }) => ((acc[name] = value), acc), {});
// Write SVG element attributes
const writeAttrs = (element, attrs) => Object.entries(attrs).forEach(([attr, value]) => element.setAttribute(attr, value));

// Process SVG shape element
// Shape elements are replaced with new <path d="..." /> element
// Shape element attributes are copied to new <path d="..." /> element
// Shape element must not have child elements
// List of shape elements <circle>, <ellipse>, <line>, <path>, <polygon>, <polyline>, <rect>
function processShape(shape) {
  const shape2path = {
    circle: ({ cx, cy, r, ...attrs }) => [
      `M ${[cx - r, cy]} A ${r} ${r} 0 1 1 ${[cx + r, cy]} A ${r} ${r} 0 1 1 ${[cx - r, cy]} Z`,
      attrs,
    ],
    line: ({ x1, y1, x2, y2, ...attrs }) => [`M ${[x1, y1]} L ${[x2, y2]}`, attrs],
    rect: ({ x, y, width, height, rx = 0, ry = 0, ...attrs }) =>
      rx == 0 && ry == 0
        ? [`M ${[x, y]} h ${width} v ${height} h -${width} Z`, attrs]
        : [
            `M ${[x + rx, y]} h  ${width - 2 * rx}  a ${rx} ${ry} 0 0 1  ${rx}  ${ry}
                              v  ${height - 2 * ry} a ${rx} ${ry} 0 0 1 -${rx}  ${ry}
                              h -${width - 2 * rx}  a ${rx} ${ry} 0 0 1 -${rx} -${ry}
                              v -${height - 2 * ry} a ${rx} ${ry} 0 0 1  ${rx} -${ry} Z`,
            attrs,
          ],
    ellipse: ({ cx, cy, rx, ry, ...attrs }) => [
      `M ${[cx - rx, cy]} A ${rx} ${ry} 0 1 1 ${[cx + 2 * rx, cy]}
                          A ${rx} ${ry} 0 1 1 ${[cx + rx, cy - ry]}
                          A ${rx} ${ry} 0 1 1 ${[cx + rx, cy + ry]}
                          A ${rx} ${ry} 0 1 1 ${[cx - rx, cy]} Z`,
      attrs,
    ],
    polygon: ({ points, ...attrs }) => [`M ${points} Z`, attrs],
    polyline: ({ points, ...attrs }) => [`M ${points}`, attrs],
  };

  // return if shape inside <pattern>, <mask> or <clipPath>
  if (shape.closest('pattern') || shape.closest('mask') || shape.closest('clipPath')) {
    return;
  }

  // create d value for new <path>
  let [d, attrs] = shape2path[shape.tagName](readAttrs(shape));
  // create new <path>
  let path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
  // write attributes from object to <path>
  writeAttrs(path, attrs);
  // set attribute "d"
  path.setAttribute('d', d);
  // replace shape with <path>
  shape.replaceWith(path);
  return path;
}

// process <path /> element
function processPath(path){
  // returns all parent Elements
  const getParents = (element)=>{
    let parents = [];
    while(element !== document.documentElement){
      parents.push(element = element.parentNode);
    }
    return parents;
  }
  // parse transform matrix
  const getMatrix = (transform) => {
    let [a, b, c, d, e, f] = transform.match(/^matrix\(([^)]+)\)$/)[1].split(',').map(Number);
    return [a, b, c, d, e, f];
  }
  // parse transform origin
  const getOrigin = (transformOrigin) => {
    // TODO Parse origin coordinates with units
    // from https://source.netsurf-browser.org/libsvgtiny.git/tree/src/svgtiny.c#n1816
    let [x, y] = transformOrigin.split(' ').map(value=>value.trim().replace(/[a-z]+$/i,'')).map(Number);
    return [x, y];
  }
  // calc origed matrix from transform and origin
  const getOTM = (element) => {
    // very useful function for read computed style
    let style = getComputedStyle(element);
    // no matter how exactly the transform is specified
    // (in attributes or in styles or in individual classes),
    // the function returns transform always in a matrix form
    let transform = style.getPropertyValue('transform');
    let transformOrigin = style.getPropertyValue('transform-origin');
    // if no transform is acquired
    if(!transform || transform == 'none') return [1,0,0,1,0,0];
    // parse transform matrix
    let matrix = getMatrix(transform);
    // parse origin
    let origin = getOrigin(transformOrigin);
    // return consolidate matrix
    return consolidate([
      [1,0,0,1,...origin],            // + origin
      matrix,
      [1,0,0,1,...origin.map(v=>-v)]  // - origin
    ]);
  }
  
  // return if <path> inside <pattern>, <mask> or <clipPath>
  if (path.closest('pattern') || path.closest('mask') || path.closest('clipPath')) {
    return;
  }

  // read element transform matrix
  const elementOTM = getOTM(path);
  // get all parent elements
  const parents = getParents(path);
  // clone element transform matrix array
  let resultCTM = [1,0,0,1,0,0];
  // for each parent
  parents.reverse().forEach((parent) => {
    // read parent transform matrix
    let parentOTM = getOTM(parent);
    // calc CTM
    resultCTM = consolidate([resultCTM,parentOTM]);
  });

  consolidate([resultCTM,elementOTM])
  
  // read d attribute, parse it, transform each point and join to single string
  let d = new D(path.getAttribute('d')).transform(resultCTM).join(' ');
  // this variant returns absolute coordinates without transform
  //let d = new D(path.getAttribute('d')).abs.join(' ');
  // remove transform attributes
  path.removeAttribute('transform');
  path.removeAttribute('transform-origin');
  // force init transform matrix
  //path.style.setProperty('transform','matrix(1,0,0,1,0,0)');
  path.style.setProperty('transform-origin', '0 0');
  // set d attribute
  path.setAttribute('d', d);
  // find root element
  let svg = path.closest('svg');
  if(svg){
    // remove element from parent
    path.parentNode.removeChild(path);
    // add element to root
    svg.appendChild(path);
  }
  return path;
}

// Process <use /> element
function  processUse(element) {
  // read attributes to object
  let attrs = readAttrs(element);
  // get href attribute value
  let sel = attrs.href;
  // find referenced element by href="#id"
  let ref = document.querySelector(sel);
  // clone referenced element
  let clone = ref.cloneNode(true);
  // remove id attribute from clone
  clone.removeAttribute('id');
  // remove href from attribute object
  delete attrs.href;
  // Create new <g>
  let group = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
  // write attributes from object
  writeAttrs(group, attrs);
  // add clone to <g>
  group.appendChild(clone);
  // replace <use> element to <g>
  element.replaceWith(group);
  return clone;
}


// Create matrix from transform attribute
// This fuction does not used.
// Use of getComputedStyle() completely replaces this implementation
function parseTransform (transform) {
  const rxTransformNameStr = '(?:(?:translate|scale|skew)[XY]?)|matrix|rotate';

  const rad = a => a / 57.29577951308232;

  const { sin, cos, tan } = Math;

  const matricies = {
    identity: () => [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
    translate: (tx, ty) => [1, 0, 0, 1, tx, ty],
    translateX: tx => [1, 0, 0, 1, tx, 0],
    translateY: ty => [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, ty],
    scale: (sx, sy = sx, cx = 0, cy = 0) => [sx, 0, 0, sy, cx * (1 - sx), cy * (1 - sy)],
    scaleX: (sx, cx = 0) => [sx, 0, 0, 1, cx * (1 - sx), 0],
    scaleY: (sy, cy = 0) => [1, 0, 0, sy, 0, cy * (1 - sy)],
    rotate: (a, cx = 0, cy = 0) => {
      let [s, c] = [sin(rad(a)), cos(rad(a))];
      return [c, s, -s, c, cx * (1 - c) + cy * s, cy * (1 - c) - cx * s];
    },
    skew: (ax, ay = ax) => [1, tan(rad(ay)), tan(rad(ax)), 1, 0, 0],
    skewX: a => [1, 0, tan(rad(a)), 1, 0, 0],
    skewY: a => [1, tan(rad(a)), 0, 1, 0, 0],
    matrix: (a, b, c, d, e, f) => [a, b, c, d, e, f],
  };

  let chain = [...transform.matchAll(new RegExp(`(${rxTransformNameStr})\\(([0-9eE,\\.\\s+-]+)\\)`, 'g'))].map(
    ([, fn, args]) => [fn, [...args.matchAll(new RegExp(rxNumberStr, 'g'))].map(([num]) => parseFloat(num))]
  );

  // For example,
  //    chain = [
  //      [ 'matrix', [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ] ],
  //      [ 'translate', [ 100, 100 ] ],
  //      [ 'rotate', [ 45 ] ],
  //      [ 'scale', [ 2, 2 ] ],
  //    ]

  chain = chain.map(([fn, args]) => matrices[fn](...args));

  // chain = [
  //   [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
  //   [ 1, 0, 0, 1, 100, 100 ],
  //   [ 0.7071067811865476, 0.7071067811865475, -0.7071067811865475, 0.7071067811865476, 0, 0 ],
  //   [ 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0 ]
  // ]

  // returns single matrix
  return consolidate(chain);
}

function groupPathList(pathList){
  let groupList = [];

  const compareStyleEquals = (s1,s2) => Object.entries(s1).every(([k,v])=>'d'==k?true:v==s2[k]);

  for(let path of pathList){
    let pathStyle = getComputedStyle(path);
    let groupFound = false;
    for(let group of groupList){
      if(compareStyleEquals(group.style,pathStyle)){
        group.list.push(path);
        groupFound = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(!groupFound){
      groupList.push({
        style: pathStyle,
        list: [path],
      });
    }
  }
  return groupList;
}

function ungroupPathList(groupList){
  let pathList = [];
  for(let group of groupList){
    let newPath = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','path');
    Object.entries(getComputedStyle(group.list[0])).forEach(([k,v])=>{if(k!=='d')newPath.style.setProperty(k,v)});
    let d = group.list.map(path=>(path.parentNode.removeChild(path),path.getAttribute('d'))).join(' ');
    d = d.replace(/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/g, num => parseFloat(num).toFixed(1));
    newPath.setAttribute('d', d);
    // this varian to run outside <svg>
    document.querySelector('svg').appendChild(newPath);
    // this variant to run inside <svg>
    //document.documentElement.appendChild(newPath);
    pathList.push(newPath);
  }
  return pathList;
}

setTimeout(()=>{

  // TODO: Parse <svg width="" height="" viewBox=""> to common CTM

  // Replace all <use /> elements to clone elements referenced by the <use>
  document.querySelectorAll('use').forEach(processUse);

  // Replace all shape elements to <path />
  document.querySelectorAll('line, rect, circle, ellipse, polygon, polyline').forEach(processShape);

  // Process all <path /> elements
  let pathList = [...document.querySelectorAll('path')].map(processPath).filter(Boolean);

  // Group all <path> into groups by style values
  let groupList = groupPathList(pathList);

  // Convert each group into single <path>
  pathList = ungroupPathList(groupList);
  
  const precisionDigits = 1;
  
  // Convert all coordinates to relative form
  pathList = pathList.map(path=>{
    let dRel = new D(path.getAttribute('d')).rel.join(' ')
      .replace(/\b[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\b/g, n => parseFloat(n).toFixed(precisionDigits))
    path.setAttribute('d', dRel);
    return dRel;
  }).map(path=>path);

  // Output new values
  console.log(JSON.stringify(pathList,null,2));

},1000); 
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">

  <g transform="translate(-100,-100)">

    <g id="hexagon" transform="translate(250,220) scale(1,.5)">
      <line id="line" x1="200" x2="500" y1="100" y2="100" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" />
      <g transform="rotate(-120)" transform-origin="500 100">
        <use href="#line" />
        <g transform="rotate(-120)" transform-origin="200 100">
          <use href="#line" />
          <g transform="rotate(-120)" transform-origin="500 100">
            <use href="#line" />
            <g transform="rotate(-120)" transform-origin="200 100">
              <use href="#line" />
              <g transform="rotate(-120)" transform-origin="500 100">
                <use href="#line" />
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>


    <g id="hexagon2" transform="translate(250,720) scale(1,.5)">
      <line id="line2" x1="200" x2="500" y1="100" y2="100" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" />
      <g transform="rotate(60) translate(-300,0)" transform-origin="200 100">
        <use href="#line2" />
        <g transform="rotate(60) translate(-300,0)" transform-origin="200 100">
          <use href="#line2" />
          <g transform="rotate(60) translate(-300,0)" transform-origin="200 100">
            <use href="#line2" />
            <g transform="rotate(60) translate(-300,0)" transform-origin="200 100">
              <use href="#line2" />
              <g transform="rotate(60) translate(-300,0)" transform-origin="200 100">
                <use href="#line2" />
              </g>
            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </g>
    </g>

    <use href="#hexagon" transform="scale(1,-1) translate(0,-1200)" />

    <rect x="500" y="500" width="200" height="400" fill="#0008" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" />
    <g transform="translate(-100,-100) skewY(-45)" transform-origin="500 500">
      <rect x="500" y="500" width="100" height="400" fill="#0004" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" />
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(-100,-100) skewY(45)" transform-origin="500 500">
      <rect x="500" y="500" width="100" height="400" fill="#0008" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" />
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(200,-200) skewY(45)" transform-origin="500 500">
      <rect x="500" y="500" width="100" height="400" fill="#0004" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" />
    </g>
    <g transform="translate(200,0) skewY(-45)" transform-origin="500 500">
      <rect x="500" y="500" width="100" height="400" fill="#0008" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" />
    </g>
    <rect x="500" y="300" width="200" height="400" fill="#0004" stroke="#000" stroke-width="5" />
  </g>

</svg>



